# Como ficam os nomes referênciados em comentários e respostas após a mudança do mesmo no Perfil

Tags: suporte, comentários, contas-usuário

Gostaria de saber como são tratados os casos em que o nome de um utilizador é referenciado em um comentário ou alguma resposta, e depois de algum tempo ele decide mudar o nome?

Observei que no meu caso (mudei de ColdHack para Cold) os comentários onde havia referência a mim não houve uma mudança automática. No meu caso até a dá pra perceber, mais se alguém sai de **Mário** (primeiro nome) para **Carlos** (último nome) fica meio estranho não?

Comment: Pelo que tenho visto não é algo que vá acontecer automaticamente. Estou postergando de ver isso em detalhes, mas cogito mudar o meu nome de usuário num futuro próximo.

Comment: Veja o link: [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31851/229289)

Comment: @utluiz Se calhar não era má ideia se mudar o Nome de utilizador, deixar uma referência ao antigo no perfil, sempre dava para tentar saber quem comentou o que...

Comment: @JorgeB. É o jeito... :S

Comment: Nesse caso recomendo fazer mudanças pouco observáveis, ou que pelomenos ajudam a perceber intuitivamente a quem se refere... como no meu caso, kkk

Comment: @utluiz Eu por acaso pensei bem no meu, não queria por nick nem nome completo, porque ninguém precisa saber, então optei por Jorge B. ;)

Comment: O nome que mais me custa "tagar" é o do bfavaretto nunca sei se estou a escrever direito :P

Comment: @JorgeB. eu sei, estou considerando mudar... Mas pode colocar `@bfa` que já me notifica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É assim que funciona mesmo, a referência faz parte de um texto, os textos não são modificados por causa da mudança do nome no perfil.

Toda identificação que gerada pelo sistema é claro que usa a nova fonte de dados, então se você posta algo com um nome e troca esse nome, todas as referências que não fazem parte de textos produzidos por usuários farão referência ao novo nome que é sempre pego do banco de dados em seu estado atual.

Fica esquisito? Fica. Mas a solução não é tão simples e provavelmente não vale o esforço. Provavelmente tem uma justificativa mais completa no [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (Metão) para o sistema não fazer a mudança mas fica claro que daria muito trabalho dar *parse* em todos os textos do site para ver onde tem uma referência para o nome do usuário e trocar. Sem falar nos possíveis falso positivos.

Tem que se acostumar com isto. Este é um dos motivos que não troco meu *nick* para meu nome mesmo.

Comment: +1 excelente resposta

Comment: boa resposta @Antonio :)

Comment: @Math quem é esse Antonio? :D Eu não me escondo, qualquer pessoa consegue saber meu nome, se quiser. Estou avisando para nenhum moderador achar que você vazou uma informação que eu não queria que aparecesse ;)

Comment: Só falei pq no seu último parágrafo você disse que pensava em por seu nome, se um dia vc trocar existirá pelo menos um comentário que já estará atualizado: o meu =P